# Regex with wildcard search?

Tags: regex

I created a Regex to check a string for the following situation:

- first 4 chars are numbers
- following by a point
- following by 3 numbers
- following by a point
- following by 4 to 8 numbers or letters

ie: `1234.123.125B`

My Regex: `^[0-9]{4}[.][0-9]{3}[.][0-9a-zA-Z]{4,8}$`

But now I need a wildcard search: The Regex should also match if there is a '*' after the first 8 characters. For example:

```
1234.123.12*   MATCH
1234.123*      MATCH
1234.123.45B9* MATCH
1234.12*       NO MATCH
1234.12345*    NO MATCH
```

How can I add the wildcard search to my Regex?
Thank you

Comment: Does this mean you would allow a wildcard ***after*** a full pattern? Should, for instance, `1234.123.12345678*` be a valid match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumptions are that:

- You don't allow wildcards to be mid-string
- Nor do you want to allow wildcards after the full pattern (e.g.: `1234.123.12345678*`).

So, alternatively you may possibily use something like:

```
^\d{4}\.\d{3}(?!.*\*.)(?![^*]{0,4}$)[.*][*\da-zA-Z]{0,8}$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ck4o2n/7).

---

- `^` - Start string ancor.
- `\d{4}\.\d{3}` - Four digits, a dot and another three digits.
- `(?!.*\*.)` - Negative lookahead for zero or more characters followed by asterisk and another character other than newline.
- `(?![^*]{0,4}$)` - Negative lookahead for zero to four characters other than asterisk before end string ancor.
- `[.*]` - A literal dot or asterisk.
- `[*\da-zA-Z]{0,8}` - Zero to eight characters from the character class.
- `$` - End string ancor.

Comment: It doesn't really need 2 negative lookaheads. It makes regex execution 2x slower than a regex without any lookahead.

Comment: Yes, processing this in bulk on 1400 sample strings appears to be about 11% faster (your regex) on my machine, so yes, kudos to you in that regard =). I guess, steps don't always equal speed.

Comment: 177 steps vs 350 steps on regex101 (verify yourself) => definitely not 11% :)

Comment: @anubhava, there was another issue with my pattern (which I fixed now). Though twice the steps do not appear to mean twice as slow (hence the 11% on processing time) you have definitely convinced me that ***no*** lookahead is faster. I'd recommend OP to reconsider accepting your answer instead!

Answer (score 4):

You may use this regex with alternation:

```
^\d{4}\.\d{3}(?:\*|\.[\da-zA-Z]{0,7}\*|\.[\da-zA-Z]{4,8})$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oj7gwf/4)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `\d{4}\.\d{3}`: Match 4 digits + 1 dot + 3 digits
- `(?:\*|\.[\da-zA-Z]{0,7}\*|\.[\da-zA-Z]{4,8})`: matches a single `*` OR a `*` after after a dot and 0 to 7 digits/letters OR match 4 to 8 digits/letters
- `$`: End

Comment: The `+` should probably be `{1,7}` or maybe `{1,8}`. That's for the OP to decide though. The pattern as is, will match `1234.123.123456789*`.

Comment: I know. I'm just pointing it out for the OP because it's something they might overlook (as it satisfies all their current examples). Nice answer though :)

Comment: That's a great answer @anubhava. I have a pattern "number of subscribers" as `"\\bnumbers?\\s+of\\s+subscribers?\\b"`. How can I put wildcard search between "number of" and then "of subscribers"?

Comment: @Roy: You can try: `"\\bnumbers?\\s+of\\b.*\\bsubscribers?\\b"`

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. It seems it's between "of subscribers". Would it be this`\\bnumbers?\\b.*\\bof`between "number of"?

Comment: Oh you have `of` on both sides. Try: `"\\bnumbers?\\s+of\\b.*\\bof\s+subscribers?\\b"`

Comment: Regarding your ideone link I don't have good knowledge of `R`. If you can post a regex101 link and tell me your expected output I can look into that.

Comment: A capture group has to be from start pattern to end pattern. If you want to skip some middle parts then you will need to use 2 capture group. First one for the pattern and second one for the date.